# Add percentages to an OLAP cube Mondrian schema

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, mondrian

I would like to calculate percentage of one of my measures.
For example:
I have a measure with aggregator distinct-count.
I would like to calculate the percentage of that measure, based on the current information.

```
For example: gender  users-distinct-count  percentage
             male    25                    25% (25/100)
             female  41                    41% (41/100)
             unk     34                    34% (34/100)
But, if I filter out unk, I want the percentage to be out of 25+41, i.e. 66

             gender  users-distinct-count  percentage
             male    25                    37.8% (25/66)
             female  41                    %62.2 (41/66)
```

I also want, that when viewing the data with different dimensions, the total sum will be updated accordingly.

I tried this:

```
<CalculatedMember name="user_percentage" caption="Users Percentage" 
    formula="[Measures].user_count/ ([Measures].user_count,[dim1].[All Dim1],[dim2].[All Dim2])" dimension="Measures" visible="true">
  </CalculatedMember>
```

but, when filtering values on the dimensions (like removing the 
"unk", the total remains the same (over all dim).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You should do it at the client level, not the schema level.

The schema has no idea what you're querying on your rows or columns, only the client does.

Some client tools allow you to create a calculated measure as a % of the visible values, but that has to be done by the query.

Example:

```
With 
  SET ROWSET as {[Gender].[Male],[Gender].[Female]}
  MEMBER [Gender].[Visible] as Aggregate( ROWSET, [Measures].[user_count] )
  MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage] as ( [Measures].[user_count], [Gender].CurrentMember ) / ( [Measures].[user_count], [Gender].[Vislble] ) 
SELECT
   ROWSET on Rows,
   { [Measures][user_count], [Measures].[Percentage] } on Columns
FROM [My Cube]
```

As you must reference the set selected on rows when defining the percentage, you cannot define it at the schema level.